# Como Indexar um array como campos separados em elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Eu tentei indexar da seguinte forma:

```
body: {
            name: form.value.name,
            title: form.value.title,
            description: form.value.description,
            published: new Date().toLocaleString(),
            stash: {
              "title": this.alternativeFields.value,
              "type": "object",
              "dynamic": true
            }
          }
```

Basicamente `this.alternativeFields.value` é um array que contêm, por exemplo:

```
["field1", "field2", "field3"]
```

E para cada posição deste array, eu gostaria de criar um campo no documento elastic.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto?

Comment: Não entendi bem. Vocẽ quer salvar cada valor do array `alternativeFields` como um campo separado? Que nomes esses campos vão ter? Por que não salvar como valores dentro do campo `title` ou outro?

Comment: Por que estes valores vão poder ser  preenchidos posteriormente.

Comment: Você pode preencher os valores depois reescrevendo o campo ou usando Scripted Updates pra atualizar itens da lista: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado